# find cell by row and column content in range and set it as integer

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I am new in VBA.
How can identify a cell that crosses with a row containing text "This Row" and a column containing text "This Column" and set the content of it as integer called MyContent? This should be searched in a range of 1000 rows and 50 columns starting from A1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngCol As Range, rngRow As Range
    Dim myContent As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngCol = .Cells.Find(What:="This Column", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        Set rngRow = .Cells.Find(What:="This Row", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

        If rngRow Is Nothing Or rngCol Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Cell with text 'This Row' in row and with text 'This Column' in column not found"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        myContent = .Cells(rngRow.Row, rngCol.Column).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Script finds the correct cell, but it overwrites the cell content with '23'. When I comment `myContent = 23` out, then the cell content will be overwritten with '0'. I would like the script to find the existing content of the cell and set an integer for it without overwriting.

Comment: change `.Cells(rngRow.Row, rngCol.Column).Value = myContent` to `myContent = .Cells(rngRow.Row, rngCol.Column).Value`